# Your Sitemap does not contain any URLs. Please validate and resubmit your Sitemap?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I am currently applying SEO on one the website. I put the sitemap.xml in the root directory but Google WebMaster showing me 'Your Sitemap does not contain any URLs. Please validate and resubmit your Sitemap.' Can anyone please suggest? I shall be really thankful.

URL: http://www.shopme.com.pk

Site: http://www.shopme.com.pk/sitemap.xml

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Try to add `<lastmod>2016-06-27T17:33:00</lastmod>` and round `priority to one decimal `1.0` , `0.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently launched your site and verified it with Google Webmaster Tools? Sometimes the process can take a few hours (or days) to fully propagate. My advice would be to try it again in a few hours and see whats going on. If its still not working after 24 hours then you might have an actual problem.  Though from visiting your link it does seem to be working but it takes a second to load the XML feed (but that could be just me).

Comment: Yes, I recently launched my website and verified it using Google Webmaster but still my site is no where in search results of Google. I submitted the sitemap like this: www.shopme.com.pk/sitemap.xml. Please confirm is this a right way? It showed me 12 pages index out of 500. I don't know why?

Comment: If you have a 500 page site it's going to take time to fully propagate into their index. Especially if they have no history of your site. It's not a right to be indexed, it's a privilege. Chances are all of your pages will not be indexed for a couple of months. It can take up to 6 to 8 months for a site that size to get indexed and ranked. Check out https://moz.com/blog, https://webmasters.googleblog.com/ or my site https://seomechanic.com/seo-blog/ for nerdy seo stuff on search indexing. But the short answer is you have to wait. A good tip: high quality links which is easier said than done.

Answer (score -1):

You must use Google Webmaster Tools.
The url link should be similar to this
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list?hl=en.

There must upload your sitemap and verify it.
This will sure increase yourseo in eyes of Google.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In that link should I use http://www.shopme.com.pk/sitemap.xml OR http://www.shopme.com.pk/index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap
Please suggest?